# Has anyone identified a good solution for iPv6 in GKE, Google Game Servers, or Agones?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking, agones

I am currently hosting a game service with Google Game Servers (https://cloud.google.com/game-servers). This is basically running Agones in GKE. This works great for the most part except when it comes to iPv6.

I am struggling to find any suggestions on how to get this kind of a setup to be iPv6 compatible. It seems like this should be the answer https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ipv6 but Agones is setup to run servers across a port range as it spins up and shuts down servers and it seems I need to have a specific port and non-persistent connections to a specific machine to use googles Load balancer solution.

For reference, this is a NodeJS backend relying on socket.io communication.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Google Cloud VPCs do not support IPv6. A few public facing services such as HTTPS Load Balancers do support IPv6 but that will not help you with internal services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in comments **Google Cloud VPCs** do not support **IPv6** connectivity:

> Google Cloud VPCs do not support IPv6. A few public facing services
> such as HTTPS Load Balancers do support IPv6 but that will not help
> you with internal services. – John Hanley Sep 29 at 12:23

If your stack requires **IPv6** connectivity, unfortunatelly you won't be able to deploy it on **Google Kubernetes Engine** at the time being as it is subject to the same rules as any other **Compute** resource on **GCP** and uses the same **VPC network**.

As you can read in the official [VPC specifications](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc):

> VPC networks only support IPv4
> [unicast](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicast) traffic. They do **not**
> support
> [broadcast](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting_(networking)),
> [multicast](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast), or IPv6 traffic
> *within* the network; VMs in the VPC network can only send to IPv4 destinations and only receive traffic from IPv4 sources. However, it
> is possible to create an IPv6 address for a [global load
> balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ipv6).

As to **Global Loadbalancer** (that **do support IPv6**)  [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ipv6) is all the information you need:

> Google Cloud supports IPv6 clients with  [HTTP(S) Load
> Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https),  [SSL
> Proxy Load
> Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl), and
> [TCP Proxy Load
> Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp). The load
> balancer accepts IPv6 connections from your users, and then proxies
> those connections to your backends.
>
> You can configure both IPv4 and IPv6 external addresses for the
> following:
>
> - external HTTP(S) load balancers
> - SSL proxy load balancers
> - TCP proxy load balancers

Protocols and port ranges it supported by each of them are listed in their individual specifications (all links available above).

[SSL Proxy Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl#open_ports):

> This does not affect SSL proxy load balancers. External forwarding
> rules, which are used in the definition of an SSL load balancer, can
> only reference TCP ports 25, 43, 110, 143, 195, 443, 465, 587, 700,
> 993, 995, 1883, 3389, 5222, 5432, 5671, 5672, 5900, 5901, 6379, 8085,
> 8099, 9092, 9200, and 9300. **Traffic with a different TCP destination
> port is not forwarded to the load balancer's backend.**

[TCP Proxy Load Balancing:](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp)

> TCP Proxy Load Balancing is intended for TCP traffic on specific
> well-known ports, such as port 25 for Simple Mail Transfer Protocol
> (SMTP). For more information, see [Port
> specifications](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts#port_specifications).
> For client traffic that is encrypted on these same ports, use [SSL
> Proxy Load
> Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl).

with one caveat:

> **Note:** TCP Proxy Load Balancing doesn't support TCP ports 80 or 8080. For HTTP traffic, use  [HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https).

When it comes to [External HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) its name speaks for itself.

So if you rather need to use some arbitrary port ranges as you mentioned, the answer is: **no, unfortunatelly you can't do that using Google Cloud Load Balancing solutions**